# Rails has_many modeling issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have a model called **Schedule** which `has_many` **Employee** objects. Each **Schedule** object runs for 2 weeks and employees are allocated to "shifts" within those 2 weeks. The point to note is that each **Schedule** has its own set of **Employee** objects.

```
class Schedule
  has_many :employees
  ...
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :schedule
  ...
end
```

The issue is that there is list of "master" employees from which the employees that are actually used in a particular **Schedule** are chosen from. Note that these master employees don't belong to a **Schedule**.

The attributes of a "master" employee are essentially the same as those of an **Employee**. However, once they get allocated to a **Schedule**, the attributes of the master employee may diverge from the attributes of an allocated **Employee**.

*So how to do this?*

A many-to-many such as the below doesn't work, since the attributes of an employee might change once allocated to a particular Schedule.

```
class ScheduleEmployee
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :schedule
  ...
end
```

The default idea would be to have a **MasterEmployee** model (with its own table), and on schedule creation, this is used to select the employees for the newly created **Schedule**:

```
class MasterEmployee
  ...
end
```

The issue with this approach is that it's not very DRY, as the attributes of a **MasterEmployee** are essentially the same as an **Employee**.

Another idea is to just have the **Employee** model, but consider the "master" employees to be those with a nil **Schedule** parent. This seems odd to me, since it feels like i'm "overloading" this model, and in particular i might want to add attributes that are only particular to either the **MasterEmployee** or the **Employee**.

STI is the next idea, but this is actually very similar to previous, in that you'd have some set of employees w/o a parent.

Any other ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a classic use case for the many-to-many association (join table). Are you sure that can't work for you? Maybe you should consider not having those mutable attributes of an employee on the `Employee` model at all, but only let that table handle the attributes that stay the same. Then your `ScheduleEmployee` model would have the foreign keys as you've shown, along with whatever attributes of an employee change from schedule to schedule.

Comment: If an Employee would have many Schedules and a Schedule has many Employees a many-to-many would be the most logical choice. What kinds of attributes will be changed based on a schedule? The EmployeeSchedule  join table could contain these attributes.

Comment: In what way might the attributes diverge?

Comment: @jvillian: An attribute like hours_per_week. Eg, an employee initially starts out at 40 hrs/week, then switches to full-time a few weeks later. sixty,sac: I like that idea of having the mutable attributes in the join table. The only issue would be a delete of an Employee, i wouldn't want these dangling references from the join table back to Employee, but i can just do a "logical" delete so the record is actually still there, just not visible going forward

Comment: I'm confused what you want. Is `Shifts` its own table? It sounds like what your really want is a mapping of `Employees` to `Shifts` and `Schedules` are just a means of blocking off `Shifts`. So unless there are some rules about how `Employees` interact with `Schedules` that your not mentioning (e.g. an `Employee` can only work once in a `Schedule` or something) I don't really see their point. Also are `MasterEmployees` just employees that aren't listed on the current `Schedule` yet?

Comment: @RoccoBasso Oh yeah, `Shifts` are their own table, and there are even more tables related to shifts (they're complicated), but not relevant to my question. A `Schedule` essentially pulls together shifts/employees. And there are definitely all kinds of rules related to how an employee gets allocated to a schedule. Eg, another attribute is `employee_type`. You can be per-diem, or full-time. The allocation rules for a per-diem are completely different from that of a full-timer. So this is another attribute that can change over time. You might start out as a per-diem, then convert to full-time.

Comment: Ok, I still might be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve but it really sounds like what you want is a many-to-many (with a join table) between `Employees` and `Shifts` and have the `Schedules` own (have-many) `Shifts`. That way you still have a reference to which `Employees` are working in a given `Schedule` (through `Shifts`) while having all the information about how many `Shifts` an `Employee` is working during a given `Schedule`, which can be used to decide if the `Employee` can work any more `Shifts` during that `Schedule`

Comment: I'm with all the comments above regarding m2m for `Schedule` to `Employee`. Since you're using all kinds of rules for allocating Employees to Schedules, you also might consider having another object, like `Availability` (or some such thing) that contains information about the Employee (like how many hours then can work, days, etc.). The Availability class could also have effective_date and expiration_date so that your rules know which Availability record to use while scheduling (which can accommodate your divergent attributes issue).